# Send WDoge through Dogechain via Python

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, dogecoin-api

I have a Metamask wallet with DogeChain connected.

I want to send WDoge coins to another wallet through DogeChain.

1. What is the best way to do this using Python?
2. Is it necessary to run an RPC server locally, or I can do it in some easy way?